# How to change gtk button-layout in KDE?

Tags: linux, kde, gtk

I am using KDE plasma as my DE, but I have to use some GTK applications. Is it possible to change button-layout in GTK window titlebar?

I want to make the title bar only left close button. Because I used gnome for some days, I know I can use `dconf` editor to make it. I found something,

```
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/button-layout
```

I changed it, but it doesn't work, then I realized that it's only for GNOME.

So could you tell me how to solve it? thx.

Answer (score 3):

For GTK-3 applications you can try setting the key
`gtk-decoration-layout` in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`.

For example:

```
# ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
[Settings]
gtk-decoration-layout=:minimize,maximize,close
```

The `gsettings` command can be used to apply these settings without restarting the desktop environment:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout :close
```